# PHP cURL - ★ symbol?

Tags: php, url, curl

I need to get json from BitSkins, so I create this code. (Below) This code works well with another URLs, but now I have a problem with this URL:

```
https://bitskins.com/api/v1/get_price_data_for_items_on_sale/?api_key=XXX&code=XXX&names=★ Bayonet,★ Bayonet | Blue Steel (Battle-Scarred),★ Bayonet | Blue Steel (Factory New)
```

My code:

```
$url = urlencode('https://bitskins.com/api/v1/get_price_data_for_items_on_sale/?api_key=XXX&code=' . $totp . '&names=' . $string);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$output = json_decode($output, true);
```

I tried also without urlencode(), but still nothing.
Could be a symbol ★ or comma in URL? (In browser URL works well)

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wouldn't want to encode the entire URL, rather only the query string values themselves.

E.G.

```
$url = 'https://bitskins.com/api/v1/get_price_data_for_items_on_sale/'
      .'?api_key=XXX&code=' . $totp . '&names=' . urlencode($string);
```

Tested and it works on this site.

Comment: Oh thank you very much I would never do this :) You helped me a lot!